# Upload one or more images to a JSON WCF Web Service

Tags: android, wcf, spring, rest

I'm developing an **Android 3.1** application using **Spring Framework for Android 1.0.0 RC1**.

I have developed a **JSON WCF web service** with **C#** and **.Net Framework 4.0**. I know how to send objects, strings, integers, etc. but I don't know how to POST an image from Android to web service.

How can I post an image?

Comment: I have same problem if you fix it lpease let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send arbitrary data to a WCF service using the raw programming model - taking a `Stream` as a parameter. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx has more information about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, How can I send an image from Android to a WCF JSON web service?